# How to check if other users are logged in on Parse via Facebook or some other way?

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform

I know that if I want to check if PFUser.currentUser is logged with Facebook, I can use:

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {

print("you logged with FB!!")

//do your stuff.

}
```

How can I know if in a blogging app, another user is logged on parse via Facebook? (or twitter? or other ways?).

**So just to be clear, I don't want to know if CURRENT USER is logged in via FB!, but if ANOTHER user is, still better HOW this user logged in.**

For example, in a class named `"posts"` under the column `"author"` I have pointer to that user in default "users" class. Is there a way, planned by Parse, in wich I can perform that check? **In their docs this case seems to be missing**, they only talk about login, linking, referring, but not checking (if not for current user).

should I insert a new column in class `User` as for example "userLoggedInBy" ??

Comment: Parse automatically makes a class called session where it shows all the current users that are logged into the app.

Comment: but how can I check if some users, to wich I have pointers, are currently connected? session is another class, and while I have 10 users, there are 62 sessions, why does it happen?

Comment: The reason that you have 62 sessions, while having 10 users is maybe because you deleted some users and never logged those users out hence the sessions are there even if the users are not. Session has a pointer to the users objectID so you can use that to check against which users are online.